# Very simple. Compiler returning "None" when I assume it should not be

Tags: python, return

I just started attempting to learn code via youtube and MIT lectures they have online.
I am using compileonline.com on the computer I'm coding on while the teacher is using the actual Python program. (Same version)  I have all the code the same as he does

```
def sqrt(x):
    ans = 0
    if x >= 0:
      while ans*ans < x: ans = ans + 1
      if ans*ans != x:
        print x, 'is not a perfect square.'
        return None
      else: return ans
   else:
       print x, 'is a negative number.'
       return None
```

Now when I add print statements to the code to test it

print sqrt(16) -- then compile and I get "4" Nothing else.
then
print sqrt(34) -- compile and I get "34 is not a perfect square" followed by "None" on the next line.  In the video the guy does his testing I guess on a different screen than where his code is written and he can simply type "sqrt(16)" instead of "print sqrt(16)" when he does, he gets 4 like I do.  But when he types "sqrt(34)" he gets "34 is not a perfect number" and thats it, no "None" below it.  This also happens for me when I test with a negative number.

My question I guess is why am I getting "None" when I use a negative number or a number that is not a perfect square?

My apologies that this is probably a terribly stupid question but I am simply trying to get exactly what he gets to ensure I'm doing this correctly and not missing something that could potentially be important.  I also wonder if this is because I am using a website and he is using the actual program?

The screen/window/box (whatever its called, its not where the code is written) the professor is using looks like this

```
>>>sqrt(16)

4 (his answer)

>>>sqrt(34)

34 is not a perfect number. (his answer)

(This is where I get "None")
```

Again, my apologies for this being overly dramatic and incredibly simple.  Just not trying to miss something and do everything/get the exact answers the professor is getting.

Comment: `else` without a colon looks weird.

Comment: You should probably install an actual python interpreter.

Comment: Like I just said.  That is code I manually typed onto the screen on this computer.  Because I am using the website compileonline.com (which loads python 2.7.4) on a different computer so I can watch the video and do what he does at the same time.  The indentation and everything is correct on the computer where I am coding.  As I stated above, I get answers, the program runs, I'm just curious as to why I am getting "none" and the professor does not.

Comment: (It's probably also a bad idea to learn python from a "professor" who thinks it's a good idea for a function called `sqrt()` to print a square root and return None...)

Answer (score 1):

You're running into confusion in the interactive terminal because of the distinction between print statements and return values.

When you run the function with a perfect square it `return`s an integer which is displayed in the console.  When you run the function using a non-perfect square it `print`s a value, which is written to the console (`sys.stdout`), then it also `return`s None, which is also displayed in the console.

Comment: So theres nothing wrong I guess?  It should be returning none?

Comment: @Nabla - It still feels like the OP's code is missing something - I'd half anticipate that the call being made is actually `print sqrt(n)`, but that's just me speculating.  Extra `None`'s in the output of an interactive terminal session are generated by the misuses of the `return` and `print` statements (generally at least).

Comment: @g.d.d.c Speculating? He explicitly says in the question that he added `print sqrt(34)` to the code to test it.

Answer (score 1):

When you type an expression into the Python interactive prompt, it normally prints the result of that expression. However, when the expression returns `None`, it doesn't print that return value. In either case, if the function you're calling performs an explicit `print`, that data is printed. That's what was happening in the video: when he called it with a square, it returned the square root, and the interactive loop printed that return value; when he called it with a non-square, the function printed `34 is not a perfect square`, and returned `None`, which the interactive loop didn't print.

The difference in your case is that you wrote `print sqrt(34)`. So you're telling it explicitly to print the return value. This has no special exception for the `None` value, so you printed `None` in the cases where the function returns that.

Answer (score 0):

You are "getting" `None` because you return `None`.

If you want to eat the `None` try something like:

```
a = sqrt(34)
if a: print (a)
```

Comment: @Nabla: I think OP said he was using compileonline.com.

Comment: @Nabla The standard python interpreter doesn't show the None, no. That's why OP is getting something different, I guess.

Comment: @Nabla: Yes I think you're right.